# Load an image file to core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm a new developer with objective c. 
I have images stored in a folder on my computer and I want to insert it to my coredata, can someone please tell me how can I do so, cause I can't find the right way for this.
By the way its my first question so get mad on me :)

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest just storing the file path to the image and not actually store the images in CoreData. Large images can cause performance issues and you don't realy gain anything my storing them in CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Entity:(b.e.: Photos), this entity need an attribute, with type is Binary Data. (b.e imageData.

Here the example to save and to show:

```
   // Save the image.    

UIImage *imageToSave;

NSManagedObject *newPhoto = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedObjectContext];
NSData *imageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageEdited, 0.7);
[newPhoto setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
[yourManagedObjectContext save:&error];

// Sow the image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[newPhoto valueForKey:@"imageData"]];
```